# Setting Histogram Bar Widths in Subplots as Equal

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting three histograms as subplots in Matplotlib, and while I can get the same number of bars for each, I keep generating different bar widths. How do I get the bar widths for each subplot to be equal? I assumed sharex=True would do it but that is clearly not the case...

Thanks!

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
f.suptitle("Nearest Neighbor", fontsize=14)

axarr[0].hist(actual_nn);
axarr[0].set_title('Actual')
axarr[1].hist(random_nn);
axarr[1].set_title('Random')![enter image description here][1]
axarr[2].hist(poisson_nn);
axarr[2].set_title('Poisson')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each bin start at different position depending of the data.
You can solve this problem by setting where the bin start with the parameter range when you call the histogram. (Don't get confuse with the function range())

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#set value for testing
actual_nn = np.random.randn(100)
random_nn = np.random.randn(100)
poisson_nn = np.random.randn(100)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
f.suptitle("Nearest Neighbor", fontsize=14)

axarr[0].hist(actual_nn, range = (-3,3)); # range parameter set the start and the end of the bin
axarr[0].set_title('Actual')
axarr[1].hist(random_nn, range = (-3,3));
axarr[1].set_title('Random')
axarr[2].hist(poisson_nn, range = (-3,3));
axarr[2].set_title('Poisson')
```

You can get more info on range parameter here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Comment: Ah that makes sense and is very straightforward, thanks!